# Why JVM Crashes frequently ....?

Tags: java, linux, sapjco3

I am getting below error while running java program in linux os..

I get below jvm crash log. It frequently crash jvm.

I am using java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64.

```
#
# An unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00002b22957ed821, pid=7719, tid=1136736576
#
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (1.6.0-b09 mixed mode linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x20a821]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://icedtea.classpath.org/bugzilla
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00002aaaf402c800):  JavaThread "CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=7758, stack(0x0000000043b13000,0x0000000043c14000)]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr=0x0000000000000000

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x00002aaaf47a3fa8, RCX=0x00002aaaf4761dd0, RDX=0x0000000043c116f8
RSP=0x0000000043c0ff00, RBP=0x0000000043c0ff70, RSI=0x00002aaaf478e700, RDI=0x00002aaaf4761dd0
R8 =0x0000000000000001, R9 =0x0000000000000000, R10=0x0000000000000000, R11=0x00002b2295715f90
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x00002aaaf47a3f70, R14=0x0000000000000001, R15=0x000000000697f0b0
RIP=0x00002b22957ed821, EFL=0x0000000000010246, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000004
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e

Top of Stack: (sp=0x0000000043c0ff00)
0x0000000043c0ff00:   0000000043c100f0 00002aaaf4642338
0x0000000043c0ff10:   0100000043c10190 0000000043c11670
0x0000000043c0ff20:   000000120002d6b0 00002aaaf4642330
0x0000000043c0ff30:   0000000243c0ff70 ffffffff00000005
0x0000000043c0ff40:   00002aaaf4761dd0 0000000043c11670
0x0000000043c0ff50:   0000000043c10190 00002b2295f9e220
0x0000000043c0ff60:   00002aaaf4293fc0 0000000043c0ffd0
0x0000000043c0ff70:   0000000043c10180 00002b22957ef4d3
0x0000000043c0ff80:   0000000000000000 0000000200000000
0x0000000043c0ff90:   0000000043c0ffa0 0000000043c10130
0x0000000043c0ffa0:   0000000043c10090 0000000043c100f0
0x0000000043c0ffb0:   0000000043c11738 00002aaaf410ba70
0x0000000043c0ffc0:   00002aaaf42943a8 00002aaaf4293fd0
0x0000000043c0ffd0:   00002b2295f65710 000000000000000e
0x0000000043c0ffe0:   0000000043c12490 0000000043c11670
0x0000000043c0fff0:   00002aaa00000c86 0000000043c10030
0x0000000043c10000:   0000000043c100a0 00002b2295bbd9f6
0x0000000043c10010:   0000000043c10190 00002b2295bbd947
0x0000000043c10020:   0000000043c10060 00002b2295bbd9f6
0x0000000043c10030:   0000000043c117d8 00002b2295bbd947
0x0000000043c10040:   0000000043c10080 00002b229579605b
0x0000000043c10050:   00002aaaf4169ac0 0000000043c117d8
0x0000000043c10060:   0000000043c10080 0000000043c11750
0x0000000043c10070:   00002aaaf402cba0 0000000000007fd8
0x0000000043c10080:   0000000043c100c0 00002b2295796147
0x0000000043c10090:   000000000000000c 0000000043c12490
0x0000000043c100a0:   00002aaaf4892cf0 00002aaaf4421560
0x0000000043c100b0:   00002aaaf410ba80 00002aaaf410da90
0x0000000043c100c0:   00002aaaf4295550 0000000043c11790
0x0000000043c100d0:   0000000043c11738 00000000000003ea
0x0000000043c100e0:   0000000043c10130 00002b22957ec82f
0x0000000043c100f0:   00002aaa0000000d 0000000043c12490 

Instructions: (pc=0x00002b22957ed821)
0x00002b22957ed811:   d0 48 8b 01 48 89 cf ff 90 80 00 00 00 49 89 c4
0x00002b22957ed821:   8b 00 21 03 41 8b 44 24 04 21 43 04 48 89 df 41 

Stack: [0x0000000043b13000,0x0000000043c14000],  sp=0x0000000043c0ff00,  free space=1011k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0x20a821]
V  [libjvm.so+0x20c4d3]
V  [libjvm.so+0x25c31d]
V  [libjvm.so+0x25d878]
V  [libjvm.so+0x1f9028]
V  [libjvm.so+0x261681]
V  [libjvm.so+0x2623bb]
V  [libjvm.so+0x5d839d]
V  [libjvm.so+0x4e1924]


Current CompileTask:
C2:175  !   com.sap.mw.jco.JCO$Record.initializeRow(I)V (1314 bytes)


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x0000000006a0c000 JavaThread "Keep-Alive-Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=18435, stack(0x000000004114c000,0x000000004124d000)]
  0x00002aaaf4096400 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=7720, stack(0x000000004021f000,0x0000000040320000)]
  0x00002aaaf400ec00 JavaThread "JCO.ServerThread-1" [_thread_in_native, id=7762, stack(0x0000000040fa3000,0x00000000410a4000)]
  0x0000000006a70c00 JavaThread "JCO.TimeoutChecker" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7761, stack(0x0000000040cdc000,0x0000000040ddd000)]
  0x00002aaaf402f000 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7759, stack(0x0000000043c14000,0x0000000043d15000)]
=>0x00002aaaf402c800 JavaThread "CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=7758, stack(0x0000000043b13000,0x0000000043c14000)]
  0x00002aaaf402b000 JavaThread "CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7757, stack(0x00000000417cd000,0x00000000418ce000)]
  0x00002aaaf4029800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7756, stack(0x0000000040ea2000,0x0000000040fa3000)]
  0x00002aaaf4000c00 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7755, stack(0x0000000043a12000,0x0000000043b13000)]
  0x0000000006994800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7754, stack(0x0000000043911000,0x0000000043a12000)]

Other Threads:
  0x000000000698f400 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000043810000,0x0000000043911000] [id=7753]
  0x00002aaaf4031000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000043d15000,0x0000000043e16000] [id=7760]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 345408K, used 283919K [0x00002aaade510000, 0x00002aaaf3a60000, 0x00002aaaf3a60000)
  eden space 341248K, 82% used [0x00002aaade510000,0x00002aaaef954858,0x00002aaaf3250000)
  from space 4160K, 24% used [0x00002aaaf3650000,0x00002aaaf374f730,0x00002aaaf3a60000)
  to   space 4096K, 0% used [0x00002aaaf3250000,0x00002aaaf3250000,0x00002aaaf3650000)
 PSOldGen        total 699072K, used 2306K [0x00002aaab3a60000, 0x00002aaade510000, 0x00002aaade510000)
  object space 699072K, 0% used [0x00002aaab3a60000,0x00002aaab3ca0a90,0x00002aaade510000)
 PSPermGen       total 21248K, used 9604K [0x00002aaaae660000, 0x00002aaaafb20000, 0x00002aaab3a60000)
  object space 21248K, 45% used [0x00002aaaae660000,0x00002aaaaefc13c8,0x00002aaaafb20000)

Dynamic libraries:
00400000-00409000 r-xp 00000000 fd:05 6553719                            /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/bin/java
00608000-0060a000 rw-p 00008000 fd:05 6553719                            /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/bin/java
068f3000-06d89000 rw-p 068f3000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
4021f000-40222000 ---p 4021f000 00:00 0 
40222000-40320000 rw-p 40222000 00:00 0 
40700000-40701000 ---p 40700000 00:00 0 
40701000-40801000 rw-p 40701000 00:00 0 
40801000-40802000 ---p 40801000 00:00 0 
40802000-40902000 rw-p 40802000 00:00 0 
40cdc000-40cdf000 ---p 40cdc000 00:00 0 
40cdf000-40ddd000 rw-p 40cdf000 00:00 0 
40ea2000-40ea5000 ---p 40ea2000 00:00 0 
40ea5000-40fa3000 rw-p 40ea5000 00:00 0 
40fa3000-40fa6000 ---p 40fa3000 00:00 0 
40fa6000-410a4000 rw-p 40fa6000 00:00 0 
4114c000-4114f000 ---p 4114c000 00:00 0 
4114f000-4124d000 rw-p 4114f000 00:00 0 
417cd000-417d0000 ---p 417cd000 00:00 0 
417d0000-418ce000 rw-p 417d0000 00:00 0 
419f2000-419f3000 ---p 419f2000 00:00 0 
419f3000-41af3000 rw-p 419f3000 00:00 0 
41af3000-41af4000 ---p 41af3000 00:00 0 
41af4000-41bf4000 rw-p 41af4000 00:00 0 
41bf4000-41bf5000 ---p 41bf4000 00:00 0 
41bf5000-41cf5000 rw-p 41bf5000 00:00 0 
41cf5000-41cf6000 ---p 41cf5000 00:00 0 
41cf6000-41df6000 rw-p 41cf6000 00:00 0 
41df6000-41df7000 ---p 41df6000 00:00 0 
41df7000-41ef7000 rw-p 41df7000 00:00 0 
41ef7000-41ef8000 ---p 41ef7000 00:00 0 
41ef8000-41ff8000 rw-p 41ef8000 00:00 0 
41ff8000-41ff9000 ---p 41ff8000 00:00 0 
41ff9000-420f9000 rw-p 41ff9000 00:00 0 
420f9000-420fa000 ---p 420f9000 00:00 0 
420fa000-421fa000 rw-p 420fa000 00:00 0 
421fa000-421fb000 ---p 421fa000 00:00 0 
421fb000-422fb000 rw-p 421fb000 00:00 0 
422fb000-422fc000 ---p 422fb000 00:00 0 
422fc000-423fc000 rw-p 422fc000 00:00 0 
423fc000-423fd000 ---p 423fc000 00:00 0 
423fd000-424fd000 rw-p 423fd000 00:00 0 
424fd000-424fe000 ---p 424fd000 00:00 0 
424fe000-425fe000 rw-p 424fe000 00:00 0 
425fe000-425ff000 ---p 425fe000 00:00 0 
425ff000-426ff000 rw-p 425ff000 00:00 0 
426ff000-42700000 ---p 426ff000 00:00 0 
42700000-42800000 rw-p 42700000 00:00 0 
42800000-42801000 ---p 42800000 00:00 0 
42801000-42901000 rw-p 42801000 00:00 0 
42901000-42902000 ---p 42901000 00:00 0 
42902000-42a02000 rw-p 42902000 00:00 0 
42a02000-42a03000 ---p 42a02000 00:00 0 
42a03000-42b03000 rw-p 42a03000 00:00 0 
42b03000-42b04000 ---p 42b03000 00:00 0 
42b04000-42c04000 rw-p 42b04000 00:00 0 
42c04000-42c05000 ---p 42c04000 00:00 0 
42c05000-42d05000 rw-p 42c05000 00:00 0 
42d05000-42d06000 ---p 42d05000 00:00 0 
42d06000-42e06000 rw-p 42d06000 00:00 0 
42e06000-42e07000 ---p 42e06000 00:00 0 
42e07000-42f07000 rw-p 42e07000 00:00 0 
42f07000-42f08000 ---p 42f07000 00:00 0 
42f08000-43008000 rw-p 42f08000 00:00 0 
43008000-43009000 ---p 43008000 00:00 0 
43009000-43109000 rw-p 43009000 00:00 0 
43109000-4310a000 ---p 43109000 00:00 0 
4310a000-4320a000 rw-p 4310a000 00:00 0 
4320a000-4320b000 ---p 4320a000 00:00 0 
4320b000-4330b000 rw-p 4320b000 00:00 0 
4330b000-4330c000 ---p 4330b000 00:00 0 
4330c000-4340c000 rw-p 4330c000 00:00 0 
4340c000-4340d000 ---p 4340c000 00:00 0 
4340d000-4350d000 rw-p 4340d000 00:00 0 
4350d000-4350e000 ---p 4350d000 00:00 0 
4350e000-4360e000 rw-p 4350e000 00:00 0 
4360e000-4360f000 ---p 4360e000 00:00 0 
4360f000-4370f000 rw-p 4360f000 00:00 0 
4370f000-43710000 ---p 4370f000 00:00 0 
43710000-43810000 rw-p 43710000 00:00 0 
43810000-43811000 ---p 43810000 00:00 0 
43811000-43911000 rw-p 43811000 00:00 0 
43911000-43914000 ---p 43911000 00:00 0 
43914000-43a12000 rw-p 43914000 00:00 0 
43a12000-43a15000 ---p 43a12000 00:00 0 
43a15000-43b13000 rw-p 43a15000 00:00 0 
43b13000-43b16000 ---p 43b13000 00:00 0 
43b16000-43c14000 rw-p 43b16000 00:00 0 
43c14000-43c17000 ---p 43c14000 00:00 0 
43c17000-43d15000 rw-p 43c17000 00:00 0 
43d15000-43d16000 ---p 43d15000 00:00 0 
43d16000-43e16000 rw-p 43d16000 00:00 0 
3dd4000000-3dd401c000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2949442                        /lib64/ld-2.5.so
3dd421b000-3dd421c000 r--p 0001b000 fd:00 2949442                        /lib64/ld-2.5.so
3dd421c000-3dd421d000 rw-p 0001c000 fd:00 2949442                        /lib64/ld-2.5.so
3dd5000000-3dd514d000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2949443                        /lib64/libc-2.5.so
3dd514d000-3dd534d000 ---p 0014d000 fd:00 2949443                        /lib64/libc-2.5.so
3dd534d000-3dd5351000 r--p 0014d000 fd:00 2949443                        /lib64/libc-2.5.so
3dd5351000-3dd5352000 rw-p 00151000 fd:00 2949443                        /lib64/libc-2.5.so
3dd5352000-3dd5357000 rw-p 3dd5352000 00:00 0 
3dd5400000-3dd5404000 r-xp 00000000 fd:05 6553834                        /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
3dd5404000-3dd5603000 ---p 00004000 fd:05 6553834                        /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
3dd5603000-3dd5604000 rw-p 00003000 fd:05 6553834                        /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
3dd5800000-3dd5802000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2949445                        /lib64/libdl-2.5.so
3dd5802000-3dd5a02000 ---p 00002000 fd:00 2949445                        /lib64/libdl-2.5.so
3dd5a02000-3dd5a03000 r--p 00002000 fd:00 2949445                        /lib64/libdl-2.5.so
3dd5a03000-3dd5a04000 rw-p 00003000 fd:00 2949445                        /lib64/libdl-2.5.so
3dd5c00000-3dd5c16000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2949446                        /lib64/libpthread-2.5.so
3dd5c16000-3dd5e15000 ---p 00016000 fd:00 2949446                        /lib64/libpthread-2.5.so
3dd5e15000-3dd5e16000 r--p 00015000 fd:00 2949446                        /lib64/libpthread-2.5.so
3dd5e16000-3dd5e17000 rw-p 00016000 fd:00 2949446                        /lib64/libpthread-2.5.so
3dd5e17000-3dd5e1b000 rw-p 3dd5e17000 00:00 0 
3dd6000000-3dd6014000 r-xp 00000000 fd:05 2720649                        /usr/lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
3dd6014000-3dd6213000 ---p 00014000 fd:05 2720649                        /usr/lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
3dd6213000-3dd6214000 rw-p 00013000 fd:05 2720649                        /usr/lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
3dd7c00000-3dd7c07000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2949448                        /lib64/librt-2.5.so
3dd7c07000-3dd7e07000 ---p 00007000 fd:00 2949448                        /lib64/librt-2.5.so
3dd7e07000-3dd7e08000 r--p 00007000 fd:00 2949448                        /lib64/librt-2.5.so
3dd7e08000-3dd7e09000 rw-p 00008000 fd:00 2949448                        /lib64/librt-2.5.so
3dd9000000-3dd900d000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2949457                        /lib64/libgcc_s-4.1.2-20080825.so.1
3dd900d000-3dd920d000 ---p 0000d000 fd:00 2949457                        /lib64/libgcc_s-4.1.2-20080825.so.1
3dd920d000-3dd920e000 rw-p 0000d000 fd:00 2949457                        /lib64/libgcc_s-4.1.2-20080825.so.1
3ddbc00000-3ddbc15000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2949465                        /lib64/libnsl-2.5.so
3ddbc15000-3ddbe14000 ---p 00015000 fd:00 2949465                        /lib64/libnsl-2.5.so
3ddbe14000-3ddbe15000 r--p 00014000 fd:00 2949465                        /lib64/libnsl-2.5.so
3ddbe15000-3ddbe16000 rw-p 00015000 fd:00 2949465                        /lib64/libnsl-2.5.so
3ddbe16000-3ddbe18000 rw-p 3ddbe16000 00:00 0 
3ddc800000-3ddc811000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2949450                        /lib64/libresolv-2.5.so
3ddc811000-3ddca11000 ---p 00011000 fd:00 2949450                        /lib64/libresolv-2.5.so
3ddca11000-3ddca12000 r--p 00011000 fd:00 2949450                        /lib64/libresolv-2.5.so
3ddca12000-3ddca13000 rw-p 00012000 fd:00 2949450                        /lib64/libresolv-2.5.so
3ddca13000-3ddca15000 rw-p 3ddca13000 00:00 0 
2aaaaaaab000-2aaaaaab3000 r--s 00061000 fd:05 6553789                    /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/ext/gnome-java-bridge.jar
2aaaaaab3000-2aaaaaab4000 r--s 00005000 fd:06 4751558                    /usr/sap/MRQ/iciciemdcheck/saaj.jar
2aaaaaab4000-2aaaaaab5000 r--s 0000a000 fd:06 4751424                    /usr/sap/MRQ/iciciemdcheck/org.apache.commons.logging_1.0.4.v20080605-1930.jar
2aaaaaab5000-2aaaaaab7000 r--s 00008000 fd:06 4751599                    /usr/sap/MRQ/iciciemdcheck/jaxrpc.jar
2aaaaaab7000-2aaaaaabb000 r--s 00020000 fd:06 4751368                    /usr/sap/MRQ/iciciemdcheck/javax.wsdl_1.5.1.v200806030408.jar
2aaaaaabb000-2aaaaaabe000 r--s 00011000 fd:06 4751604                    /usr/sap/MRQ/iciciemdcheck/commons-discovery-0.2.jar
2aaaaaabe000-2aaaaaad2000 r--s 0017d000 fd:06 4751566                    /usr/sap/MRQ/iciciemdcheck/axis.jar
2aaaaaad2000-2aaaaaad4000 r--s 00007000 fd:06 4751374                    /usr/sap/MRQ/iciciemdcheck/TechProUtil.jar
2aaaaaaf4000-2aaaaaaf5000 r--p 2aaaaaaf4000 00:00 0 
2aaaaaaf5000-2aaaaaaf6000 rwxp 2aaaaaaf5000 00:00 0 
2aaaaaaf6000-2aaaaaafe000 r-xp 00000000 fd:05 6553766                    /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/native_threads/libhpi.so
2aaaaaafe000-2aaaaacfd000 ---p 00008000 fd:05 6553766                    /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/native_threads/libhpi.so
2aaaaacfd000-2aaaaacfe000 rw-p 00007000 fd:05 6553766                    /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/native_threads/libhpi.so
2aaaaacfe000-2aaaaacff000 rw-p 2aaaaacfe000 00:00 0 
2aaaaacff000-2aaaaad07000 rw-s 00000000 fd:01 1572868                    /tmp/hsperfdata_mrqadm/7719
2aaaaad07000-2aaaaad2e000 r--s 00266000 fd:06 4751654                    /usr/sap/MRQ/iciciemdcheck/client.jar
2aaaaad47000-2aaaaad51000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2949147                    /lib64/libnss_files-2.5.so
2aaaaad51000-2aaaaaf50000 ---p 0000a000 fd:00 2949147                    /lib64/libnss_files-2.5.so
2aaaaaf50000-2aaaaaf51000 r--p 00009000 fd:00 2949147                    /lib64/libnss_files-2.5.so
2aaaaaf51000-2aaaaaf52000 rw-p 0000a000 fd:00 2949147                    /lib64/libnss_files-2.5.so
2aaaaaf52000-2aaaaaf60000 r-xp 00000000 fd:05 6553763                    /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
2aaaaaf60000-2aaaab15f000 ---p 0000e000 fd:05 6553763                    /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
2aaaab15f000-2aaaab161000 rw-p 0000d000 fd:05 6553763                    /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
2aaaab161000-2aaaab18d000 r-xp 00000000 fd:05 6553744                    /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
2aaaab18d000-2aaaab38c000 ---p 0002c000 fd:05 6553744                    /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
2aaaab38c000-2aaaab390000 rw-p 0002b000 fd:05 6553744                    /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
2aaaab390000-2aaaab397000 r-xp 00000000 fd:05 6553764                    /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
2aaaab397000-2aaaab596000 ---p 00007000 fd:05 6553764                    /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
2aaaab596000-2aaaab597000 rw-p 00006000 fd:05 6553764                    /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
2aaaab597000-2aaaab807000 rwxp 2aaaab597000 00:00 0 
2aaaab807000-2aaaae597000 rwxp 2aaaab807000 00:00 0 
2aaaae597000-2aaaae5a1000 rwxp 2aaaae597000 00:00 0 
2aaaae5a1000-2aaaae657000 rwxp 2aaaae5a1000 00:00 0 
2aaaae660000-2aaaafb20000 rwxp 2aaaae660000 00:00 0 
2aaaafb20000-2aaab3a60000 rwxp 2aaaafb20000 00:00 0 
2aaab3a60000-2aaaf3a6b000 rwxp 2aaab3a60000 00:00 0 
2aaaf3a6b000-2aaaf3a8a000 rwxp 2aaaf3a6b000 00:00 0 
2aaaf3a8a000-2aaaf3dec000 rwxp 2aaaf3a8a000 00:00 0 
2aaaf3dec000-2aaaf3e0b000 rwxp 2aaaf3dec000 00:00 0 
2aaaf3e0b000-2aaaf3e33000 rw-p 2aaaf3e0b000 00:00 0 
2aaaf3e33000-2aaaf3fc4000 r--s 033e8000 fd:05 6553832                    /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar
2aaaf3fc4000-2aaaf3ff7000 rw-p 2aaaf3fc4000 00:00 0 
2aaaf4000000-2aaaf4b72000 rw-p 2aaaf4000000 00:00 0 
2aaaf4b72000-2aaaf8000000 ---p 2aaaf4b72000 00:00 0 
2aaaf8000000-2aaaf8441000 rw-p 2aaaf8000000 00:00 0 
2aaaf8441000-2aaafba19000 r--p 00000000 fd:05 6326487                    /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
2aaafba19000-2aaafba1c000 r--s 00048000 fd:06 4751565                    /usr/sap/MRQ/iciciemdcheck/sapjco.jar
2aaafba1c000-2aaafba20000 r--s 00079000 fd:05 6553818                    /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/jsse.jar
2aaafba20000-2aaafba28000 r--s 0004f000 fd:06 4751548                    /usr/sap/MRQ/iciciemdcheck/log4j-1.2.8.jar
2aaafba28000-2aaafbdbb000 r-xp 00000000 fd:06 4751402                    /usr/sap/MRQ/iciciemdcheck/libsapjcorfc.so
2aaafbdbb000-2aaafbeba000 ---p 00393000 fd:06 4751402                    /usr/sap/MRQ/iciciemdcheck/libsapjcorfc.so
2aaafbeba000-2aaafbec0000 rw-p 00392000 fd:06 4751402                    /usr/sap/MRQ/iciciemdcheck/libsapjcorfc.so
2aaafbec0000-2aaafc255000 r-xp 00000000 fd:06 4751656                    /usr/sap/MRQ/iciciemdcheck/librfccm.so
2aaafc255000-2aaafc355000 ---p 00395000 fd:06 4751656                    /usr/sap/MRQ/iciciemdcheck/librfccm.so
2aaafc355000-2aaafc3d2000 rw-p 00395000 fd:06 4751656                    /usr/sap/MRQ/iciciemdcheck/librfccm.so
2aaafc3d2000-2aaafc4f6000 rw-p 2aaafc3d2000 00:00 0 
2aaafc4f6000-2aaafc4f7000 r--p 2aaafc4f6000 00:00 0 
2aaafc53e000-2aaafc5ff000 r-xp 00000000 fd:05 2721977                    /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.5.0.7
2aaafc5ff000-2aaafc7ff000 ---p 000c1000 fd:05 2721977                    /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.5.0.7
2aaafc7ff000-2aaafc808000 rw-p 000c1000 fd:05 2721977                    /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.5.0.7
2aaafc808000-2aaafc819000 rw-p 2aaafc808000 00:00 0 
2aaafc819000-2aaafc820000 r--s 00000000 fd:05 2719998                    /usr/lib64/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
2aaafc820000-2aaafcedb000 rw-p 2aaafc820000 00:00 0 
2aaafcedb000-2aaafceef000 r-xp 00000000 fd:05 6553756                    /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/libnet.so
2aaafceef000-2aaafd0ee000 ---p 00014000 fd:05 6553756                    /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/libnet.so
2aaafd0ee000-2aaafd0ef000 rw-p 00013000 fd:05 6553756                    /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/libnet.so
2aaafd0ef000-2aaafd270000 rw-p 2aaafd0ef000 00:00 0 
2aaafd270000-2aaafd273000 r--s 00031000 fd:05 6553792                    /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar
2aaafd273000-2aaafd276000 r--s 00014000 fd:05 6553816                    /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/jce.jar
2aaafd276000-2aaafd27d000 r--s 000f9000 fd:05 6553831                    /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/resources.jar
2aaafd2b8000-2aaafd2bc000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2949145                    /lib64/libnss_dns-2.5.so
2aaafd2bc000-2aaafd4bb000 ---p 00004000 fd:00 2949145                    /lib64/libnss_dns-2.5.so
2aaafd4bb000-2aaafd4bc000 r--p 00003000 fd:00 2949145                    /lib64/libnss_dns-2.5.so
2aaafd4bc000-2aaafd4bd000 rw-p 00004000 fd:00 2949145                    /lib64/libnss_dns-2.5.so
2b2295596000-2b2295598000 rw-p 2b2295596000 00:00 0 
2b22955e0000-2b22955e3000 rw-p 2b22955e0000 00:00 0 
2b22955e3000-2b2295d1f000 r-xp 00000000 fd:05 6553770                    /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
2b2295d1f000-2b2295f1f000 ---p 0073c000 fd:05 6553770                    /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
2b2295f1f000-2b2295f97000 rw-p 0073c000 fd:05 6553770                    /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
2b2295f97000-2b2295fd0000 rw-p 2b2295f97000 00:00 0 
2b2296018000-2b229609a000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2949447                    /lib64/libm-2.5.so
2b229609a000-2b2296299000 ---p 00082000 fd:00 2949447                    /lib64/libm-2.5.so
2b2296299000-2b229629a000 r--p 00081000 fd:00 2949447                    /lib64/libm-2.5.so
2b229629a000-2b229629b000 rw-p 00082000 fd:00 2949447                    /lib64/libm-2.5.so
7fffb9ae3000-7fffb9af8000 rw-p 7ffffffea000 00:00 0                      [stack]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffffe00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0                  [vdso]

VM Arguments:
java_command: EMDPayCheck
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
CLASSPATH=/usr/sap/MRQ/iciciemdcheck/saaj.jar:/usr/sap/MRQ/iciciemdcheck/org.apache.commons.logging_1.0.4.v20080605-1930.jar:/usr/sap/MRQ/iciciemdcheck/jaxrpc.jar:/usr/sap/MRQ/iciciemdcheck/javax.wsdl_1.5.1.v200806030408.jar:/usr/sap/MRQ/iciciemdcheck/commons-discovery-0.2.jar:/usr/sap/MRQ/iciciemdcheck/axis.jar:/usr/sap/MRQ/iciciemdcheck/TechProUtil.jar:/usr/sap/MRQ/iciciemdcheck/client.jar:/usr/sap/MRQ/iciciemdcheck/sapjco.jar:/usr/sap/MRQ/iciciemdcheck/log4j-1.2.8.jar:/usr/sap/MRQ/iciciemdcheck
PATH=/oracle/MRQ/102_64/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/sap/MRQ/SYS/exe/uc/linuxx86_64:/usr/sap/MRQ/SYS/exe/run:/home/mrqadm:.
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/sap/MRQ/iciciemdcheck
SHELL=/bin/csh
HOSTTYPE=x86_64-linux
OSTYPE=linux
MACHTYPE=x86_64

Signal Handlers:
SIGSEGV: [libjvm.so+0x618c70], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGBUS: [libjvm.so+0x618c70], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGFPE: [libjvm.so+0x4dcd80], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGPIPE: SIG_IGN, sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGXFSZ: [libjvm.so+0x4dcd80], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGILL: [libjvm.so+0x4dcd80], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGUSR1: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGUSR2: [libjvm.so+0x4e02a0], sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGHUP: [libjvm.so+0x4de1b0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGINT: [libjvm.so+0x4de1b0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGTERM: [libjvm.so+0x4de1b0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGQUIT: [libjvm.so+0x4de1b0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004


---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS:Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.4 (Tikanga)

uname:Linux 2.6.18-164.el5 #1 SMP Tue Aug 18 15:51:48 EDT 2009 x86_64
libc:glibc 2.5 NPTL 2.5 
rlimit: STACK 10240k, CORE 0k, NPROC 1056768, NOFILE 32800, AS infinity
load average:0.15 0.14 0.08

CPU:total 32 (8 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 15 stepping 2, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3

Memory: 4k page, physical 132098008k(7635972k free), swap 52428792k(52408872k free)

vm_info: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (1.6.0-b09) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.6.0-b09), built on Aug  5 2009 11:16:51 by "mockbuild" with gcc 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-44)

time: Sat Jul 22 02:23:59 2017
elapsed time: 36508 seconds
```

I am using SAPJCO jars. What this error is exactly and how to solve?

Comment: Can't you use a modern, supported version of Java? This one is version 1.6 (ancient), and it's a JVM by Iced Tea. If you can install a modern Oracle JVM it could save you a lot of problems.

Comment: yeah we just migrated from AIX System to RedHat Linux system..Previously on AIX system we were using sun jdk 1.4 we were not getting this error before migration. After migration we used open jdk 1.6 which by default installed in server.....so using oracle jdk will solve problem ?

Comment: Agree with the comment... I think you'd have to contact Iced Tea for help and hope they're willing to support an old version (good luck)

Comment: Side note: as per SAP note 1077727, only IBM or Oracle JSE is supported on Linux for JCo 3; see note 549268 for JCo2 requirements and support status.

Comment: I echo the above comments, but for the server version as well.  Looks like it is: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.4.  All these versions are akin to trying to get something to run on Win '95.  Even if you make it work, it will be a security nightmare - time to upgrade!